# Image download using Async Http Client Library

Tags: android

I am trying to download image resource from a URL using [AsyncHttpClient library by loopj](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) and I do not know why I am not able to save it to internal storage. My problem is I don't see any image file in internal storage on running the below code but I do not see any error in logs or at compile time. Both of the below Toast statements work. Here is the code I am using.

Code:

```
String[] allowedTypes = new String[] { "image/png" };
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("http://example.com/dock.png",
            new BinaryHttpResponseHandler(allowedTypes) {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successful in finding file",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream((new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)   + File.separator + "imgdwo.png")));
                        f.write(bytes); //your bytes
                        f.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes, Throwable throwable) {

                }


    });
```

Update: I changed the hardcoded location on internal memory but that doesn't fix the issue. The logcat is below:

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
 06-29 09:07:28.721  17675-17675/com.example.abhishek.asynchttpclient W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
 06-29 09:07:28.721  17675-17675/com.example.abhishek.asynchttpclient W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
 06-29 09:07:28.721  17675-17675/com.example.abhishek.asynchttpclient W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:128)
 06-29 09:07:28.721  17675-17675/com.example.abhishek.asynchttpclient W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:117)
 06-29 09:07:28.721  17675-17675/com.example.abhishek.asynchttpclient W/System.err﹕ at com.example.abhishek.asynchttpclient.AsyncActivity$1.onSuccess(AsyncActivity.java:41)
 06-29 09:07:28.721  17675-17675/com.example.abhishek.asynchttpclient W/System.err﹕ at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:311)
 06-29 09:07:28.721  17675-17675/com.example.abhishek.asynchttpclient W/System.err﹕ at   com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:138)
 06-29 09:07:28.721  17675-17675/com.example.abhishek.asynchttpclient W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 06-29 09:07:28.721  17675-17675/com.example.abhishek.asynchttpclient W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 06-29 09:07:28.721  17675-17675/com.example.abhishek.asynchttpclient W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
 06-29 09:07:28.721  17675-17675/com.example.abhishek.asynchttpclient W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 06-29 09:07:28.721  17675-17675/com.example.abhishek.asynchttpclient W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 06-29 09:07:28.721  17675-17675/com.example.abhishek.asynchttpclient W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
 06-29 09:07:28.721  17675-17675/com.example.abhishek.asynchttpclient W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
 06-29 09:07:28.721  17675-17675/com.example.abhishek.asynchttpclient W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 06-29 09:07:28.721  17675-17675/com.example.abhishek.asynchttpclient W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
 06-29 09:07:28.721  17675-17675/com.example.abhishek.asynchttpclient W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
 06-29 09:07:28.726  17675-17675/com.example.abhishek.asynchttpclient W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
 06-29 09:07:28.726  17675-17675/com.example.abhishek.asynchttpclient W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
 06-29 09:07:28.726  17675-17675/com.example.abhishek.asynchttpclient W/System.err﹕ ... 14 more
```

Comment: if you are getting any error, post your locat stacktrace..

Comment: No error. Not in logs or at compile time. Just I don't get the image file in internal storage. Both toast work as in above code.

Comment: Are you sure whether the size of the image file your are writng are same as that of bytes[] you are writing to the external storage?

Comment: No not really.  Is there a work around? The image is small though.

Comment: "http://example.com/dock.png" did you change this url to a real image ?

Comment: try to flush the stream after write ?

Comment: What's this new File("/sdcard/nwes.png"))? Never hardcode a path, use for example File root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); this can solve your problem if the image is downloaded, and please, share the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Points to be noted,

1. You have to make sure, that there is no directory with the same name that already exists before. Try to remove the directory before creating the FileOutputStream.
2. Use `new FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler(Context)` constructor, it will automatically create temporary file in you app's cache directory, you can then move the file, rename it, modify it's content, or delete it.

Comment: I do not have any file with the same name. I am dying to find one.

Answer (score 0):

use this code for create the dir if not exists and create the file after.

```
                        Bitmap mIcon;
                        File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
if (!dir.exists()) {
                    //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
                    dir.mkdir();
                }
String fname = "myimage.png";
File myimage =  new File(dir, fname);
                        try {
                        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(imageurl).openStream();
                        mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

                        try {
                            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myimage);
                            mIcon.compress(
                                    Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,
                                    100, out);
                            out.flush();
                            out.close();
                            return myimage;

                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            return null;
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            return null;
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        return null;
                    }
```

This code download the image and save it in directory and name that you want. Use it and share any error.

Comment: Where exactly should I check for the file because I still can't find it?

Comment: What do you want? Verify if the file exists? The code above create the file, if your bytes is not correct your file is not created. Update the code and share the new logcat.

Comment: @JawaharSingh I update the answer with more complete code how download and save an image from url.